# Deserializing data from Rails API to Angular 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I'm trying to call a Rails backend API and return some simple data - an array of models. For example, I have a car model, that has properties for make, year and price.

The Angular 2 model is similarly defined.

When making the http get call to the Rails app:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def index
        respond_with Car.all.order(:make)
    end
end
```

the rails app will return the data as a jSON array of objects that are each wrapped in an object:

```
[ { car: { year: 2017, Make: Honda, Model: Accord } }, 
  { car: { year: 2010, Make: Toyota, Model: Solara } }
]
```

etc

The Angular2 routine to call for, and convert the returned data:

```
  getCars(): Observable<Car[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
                    .map(this.extractData)    
                    .catch((res: Response ) => this.handleError(res));
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
```

does not work - it returns an empty object, as it expects the data to not have each object enclosed within another object.

How do I get Angular2 to do the right thing? How can I convert the returned data so Angular2 will populate my array of Cars correctly?

(I can't believe I can't find any reference to this issue when searching!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be with that you are sending back an array as response instead of key value pair. If I recall correctly, AngularJS had special case when API was returning array.